# Win32 Shortcut Menu doesn't send messages in any case

Tags: c, winapi

I have a **shortcut menu** that I display but no matter what I do with it, **it doesn't send any messages.**

**I tried it in a high level mouse hook**, **tried it in WM_CONTEXTMENU** window procedure message. **No matter what I will do, what I return, it never sends a message.**

The menu is created during application launch, destroyed when application is closing down.

Here is the menu creation code:

```
DoomRatGUI_SlavesListItemMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
DoomRatGUI_SlavesListItemMenuInfo = calloc(1, sizeof(MENUINFO));
DoomRatGUI_SlavesListItemMenuInfo->fMask = MIM_STYLE | MIM_APPLYTOSUBMENUS;
DoomRatGUI_SlavesListItemMenuInfo->cbSize = sizeof(MENUINFO);
DoomRatGUI_SlavesListItemMenuInfo->dwStyle = MNS_NOCHECK | MNS_NOTIFYBYPOS;
//DoomRatGUI_SlavesListItemMenuInfo->hbrBack = ResourcesManager_GetDarkGreyBrush();
SetMenuInfo(DoomRatGUI_SlavesListItemMenu, DoomRatGUI_SlavesListItemMenuInfo);
AppendMenuW(DoomRatGUI_SlavesListItemMenu, MF_STRING, 1001, L"Actions");
AppendMenuW(DoomRatGUI_SlavesListItemMenu, MF_STRING, 1002, L"Quick Info");
AppendMenuW(DoomRatGUI_SlavesListItemMenu, MF_STRING, 1003, L"Quick Stop");
AppendMenuW(DoomRatGUI_SlavesListItemMenu, MF_STRING, 1004, L"Quick Restart");
```

I show the menu using the line of code:

```
TrackPopupMenu(DoomRatGUI_SlavesListItemMenu, TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_TOPALIGN | TPM_RETURNCMD | TPM_LEFTBUTTON | TPM_NOANIMATION, LOWORD(Arg_lParam), HIWORD(Arg_lParam), 0, DoomRatGUI_WindowHandle, NULL);
```

If you know a solution tell me what I have to do because I have tried everything, like... where to put that piece of code exactly, Thanks.

PS: **DoomRAT isn't anything malicious, its a tiny 2D game** I am working on for learning.

Comment: Have you even looked up the MSDN documentation for TrackPopupMenu()? That would propably have been faster than writing this SO question.

Comment: It's a modal thingy - it has it's own message-handler internally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TPM_RETURNCMD` flag causes `TrackPopupMenu` to return the chosen menu item id as the functions return value instead of sending a `WM_COMMAND` message.

Also, allocating `MENUINFO` like that is unnecessary, it is a small struct, just use the stack.

Comment: I am pretty sure I tried removing TMP_RETURNCMD and it didn't work before but now it does! Thanks!